Jacobian of a variational formulation
Background
I am solving a nonlinear problem that is mixed domain and also mixed finite element. I have the variational formulation and want to take the Jacobian so that I can solve the problem using Newton-Raphson. The software I use can generate the Jacobian, but I want to solve, by hand, a smaller problem with a few elements on an interval to get a feel for the numerical issues. My challenge is obtaining the Jacobian.
Illustrative Problem
Here's a simple problem where $u$ is the trial function, $v$ is the test function and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the source function. For simplicity, assume Dirichlet boundary condition of zero and $\Omega$ is the line interval $0<x<1$, that is divided into N elements.
$$
F = \int_{\Omega}\kappa \nabla u \cdot \nabla v\mathrm{d\Omega} - \int_{\Omega} f v\mathrm{d\Omega}
$$
The Jacobian is $J = \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$.
Now, take $u = \sum_{i=0}^N \xi_i\phi_i$ where $\phi_i=\phi_i(x)$ is a piecewise linear basis function and $\xi_i$ is the coefficient.
My source of confusion is that $u$ is a function of the coefficients $\xi_i$ and basis functions $\phi_i(x)$. So will the Jacobian involve derivatives of $F$ with respect to $\xi_i$ and $x$? How does the expression look like?
(Aside: Since my problem $F(u)$ is linear, it should converge in one iteration of Newton's method. Once I know the expression for $J$, I can generate matrices for my complicated problem.)

Do you know how to compute the functional derivative $dF/du$ for a functional like the one shown above? Or is your question just on how to translate such an expression into a FEM setting?

I think the latter, how to translate that to FEM setting. Since the problem is linear, I know that the Jacobian will be the same as the stiffness matrix that I generate such that $J_{ik} = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial \xi_k}$ where $F_i = \int_{\Omega}\sum_j \nabla (\xi_j\phi_j)\cdot \nabla \phi_i \mathrm{d\Omega} - \int_{\Omega}f_j\phi_i\mathrm{d\Omega}$. I'm having trouble rationalizing why we don't take derivatives with respect to the basis functions $\phi_m$.

Recall that the weak form of a nonlinear PDE $F(u)=0$ is given by $\langle v,F(u)\rangle=0$ $\forall v\in\mathcal{V}$. To obtain the Jacobian of the lefthand side, we perturb the state by $\delta u$ and use the linearity of the inner product to obtain
$$
\langle v,F(u+\delta u)\rangle = \langle v,F(u)\rangle + \langle v,dF(u)\delta u\rangle + \mathcal{O}(\|\delta u\|^2).
$$
$dF(u)$ is the Jacobian of $F$ at the point $u$ and is a linear operator. For example, if $F(u) = -\nabla^2 u + \frac{1}{2}u^2$, then the Jacobian would be given by $dF(u)\delta u = -\nabla^2(\delta u) + u\delta u$, which is linear in the perturbation $\delta u$, as desired.
Now consider how we represent a linear map $L$ in a finite element context: we select a finite-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{V}_h\subset \mathcal{V}$ with basis $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}$ then represent $L$ on $\mathcal{V}$ in terms of this basis. In particular, we obtain
$$
\mathbf{L}_{ij} = \langle \phi_i, L\phi_j\rangle.
$$
We can apply the same logic to the Jacobian $dF[u]$. The only part that is different is that we also have to take into account the fact that $dF$ depends explicitly on $u$, which is an element of $\mathcal{V}_h$. If we denote this approximation by $u_h$, then we have
$$
\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{u})_{ij} = \langle \phi_i, dF(u)\phi_j\rangle \approx \langle \phi_i, dF(u_h)\phi_j \rangle,
$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is the vector of coefficients of $u_h = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\phi_i$.
The approach we have taken here is subtley different from what you are proposing. Your approach proceeds by writing down the discretized nonlinear equations in terms of coefficients and shape functions, then differentiating with respect to the coefficients. My approach differentiates the infinite-dimensional operator, then approximates its action in the discretized space. These two appraoches are commonly referred to as discretize-then-optimize (DTO) and optimize-then-discretize (OTD). For simple problems, the results are identical, but OTD tends to be preferred and is better behaved in many isntances due to the fact that the infinite-dimensional formulation can be transferred between different meshes and grids, among other things.

At first, I didn't think about the problem directly from the perturbation. Now it makes sense, thank you.
